# MQTT Subscribe does not receive messages after few hours

Tags: java, networking, mqtt, paho

I am using Paho MQTT (java) to subscribe (QoS 2) to VerneMQ broker. I have a device which constantly (every 2 seconds) publishes data to broker. Everything works fine until after 3 - 4 hours, my MQTT Subscriber program does not receive anything, but it is still connected and is running (I will name this condition as sleep).

However, when there is another MQTT Subscriber subscribing to the same topic, the sleeping MQTT Subscriber program start to receives message again.  If I have at least 2 subscribers subscribing on every topics I have, it works fine. Any solutions on this situation?

Comment: Have you tried a different broker?

Comment: Nope, not yet. I am currently finding for broker which supports clustering and budget friendly(well VernMQ is open source). VernMQ comes to my first choice previously.

Comment: But to test with a single client doesn't need any of those features

Comment: Ok. I will give it a try with rabbitmq. Hope it solves the problem next 3-4 hours.

Comment: I seems fine for me when i am using RabbitMQ as my broker. So I supposed VerneMQ is faulty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using VerneMQ 0.12.4? There was a known issue regarding UNSUBSCRIBE in previous versions.

If you're using 0.12.4 please get in touch with us!

Cheers,

Andre from
[VerneMQ](http://verne.mq)

PS:
I'll update the answer as soon as we've more insights about the issue

Comment: I am currently using version 0.11.1. I am not running any UNSUBSCRIBE commands yet. The issue occurs 3-4 hours after i ran the SUBSCRIBE command. I will try to upgrade to 0.12.4 and give it a try.